# Email info in table in a PDF required to put an anchor in the generated PDF, such that on click of that email, open outlook window

Tags: java

This is the code :

```
table = new Table(1);

cell = new Cell(new Phrase("    9) Transportation charges will be covered by GE for returns due to GE error."+
                        "Once you have obtained an RGA, please contact the GE Routing Center by calling"+
                        "1-800-958-5785 or emailing routing.center@ge.com for carrier instructions and authorization. ",
                        FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.defaultEncoding, 8, Font.NORMAL, new Color(0, 0, 0))));
                cell.setHeader(true);
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                cell.setBorder(0);
                table.addCell(cell);

return (Element) table;
```

Comment: Hi Guys, Please help in this urgently as I need to complete it soon today by 4 PM IST.

Comment: 1) please format your code to make it more readable 2) explain your problem more to provide enough detail to solve the problem *side note* dont ask for things to be rushed on stack overflow

Comment: I have to place some data in a table in a PDF, which has email information, it is required to put an anchor in the generated PDF, such that on click of that email, outlook window with pre-filled subject is opened and email can be sent directly by adding message to it.